# How do I make slow scroll Parallax background a dynamic height and remove bottom white space with just CSS and vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

Most Parallax walkthroughs assume you either want the background image to remain still, or you want to do full-viewport images, then scroll to another full-viewport image. I don't want either of these thing, I just want my boring background image to have a bit more pizazz and scroll at a different rate.

To make a background image have a parallax effect and scroll slower than the content of the page (with only CSS) I placed the background image into a div with `position: absolute` and `transform: translateZ(-3px)`. Then, to make it the right size again, I used `scale(4)`. To make it start at the top of the image (with translateZ -3) I put `top:-150vh`, but all of this causes there to be a not insignificant amount of white-space at the end of the webpage as the image ends. I also have no idea how to make the image dynamically resize to fit the content of the page instead of `height: 100%` being precisely the size of 1 viewscreen. How can I make my background image behave like a background image and also fill the whole page?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178057/scroll-background-relative-to-page) doesn't work as well as I want, because rapid scrolling with that javascript looks bouncy and Skrollr hasn't been supported in more than 5 years. Initially, I envisioned this project as a "back to roots" only vanilla JS, CSS, and HTML. I would rather do it this format if possible, but at this point I just want it to work, be performant, and as simple as possible.

I've tried negative margins and padding for both `#background-pic` and `#background-pic:after` for the white space and changing `#page-container` into a table and the two .parallax divs into tds so that they conform sizes, but that isn't working for me, though I don't have a lot of experience with tables in HTML. Here's basically what I have so far, sorry for the bloated HTML, but I wanted it to be scrollable. Notice the white space at the bottom and the non-dynamic background size.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#page-container {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.parallax {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  #background-pic {
    background-image: url(http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/backdrops/wood/preview/bark.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    top: -150vh;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: translateZ(-3px) scale(4);
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Parallax Fiddle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-container">
      <div class="parallax">
        <div id="background-pic"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, et veritatis. Similique
          ipsam saepe voluptatem perferendis possimus cumque voluptas asperiores accusamus in 
          dolorum. Iste culpa animi corporis ducimus repudiandae error!
        </h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam
            laborum architecto, dolorem unde voluptatibus quam excepturi
            laboriosam accusamus dolore in, est ea. Hic voluptatum pariatur
            commodi sequi magni blanditiis velit.
        </h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam
          laborum architecto, dolorem unde voluptatibus quam excepturi
          laboriosam accusamus dolore in, est ea. Hic voluptatum pariatur
          commodi sequi magni blanditiis velit.
        </h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam
          laborum architecto, dolorem unde voluptatibus quam excepturi
          laboriosam accusamus dolore in, est ea. Hic voluptatum pariatur
          commodi sequi magni blanditiis velit.
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```